# Can not remove a permission of lambda function in AWS CLI

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cli

I can add permission to Lambda function with the `aws lambda add-permission` command in AWS CLI. But I can't remove permission using `aws lambda remove-permission` command. 
I run this command:

```
aws lambda remove-permission --function-name LAMBDA_NAME --statement-id SID
```

Here is the error:

```
An error occurred (ServiceException) when calling the RemovePermission
operation (reached max retries: 4): An error occurred and the request
cannot be processed.
```

Hope someone helps.

Comment: Share the command you run as well.. this error message is to broad.

Comment: can you add debug output? You can do this with the --debug flag appended at the end of the command.

Comment: @jmp, I'm getting the same thing on my IAM User Account that has privileges to remove lambda permissions.  When I add the --debug flag, I see this: 

 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - https://lambda.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:443 "DELETE /2015-03-31/functions/GetEnvironment/policy/invoke_lw59n63vcf HTTP/1.1" 500 85

Comment: Same here. With `--debug` I get: `MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - https://lambda.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443 "DELETE /2015-03-31/functions/euw1-test-20201201/policy/my-sid HTTP/1.1" 500 85` with unhelpful response body: `{"Message":"An error occurred and the request cannot be processed.","Type":"Service"}`.

Comment: I notice that it gives me this error when try to delete statement ids that aren't uuids/guids. If I delete statement ids with uuids/guids, it works.